# Interesting effect. From where to start?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

[image]

Greetings, I've recently came across this poster and would like to learn how the background effect was achieved, can you please suggest tips in order to start moving on.

Comment: What have you tried in illustrator or Photoshop to achieve the effect you're looking for? For me, I have always found I learn the most when I try solving the problem on my own first, before I ask for help.

Comment: That is really cool. Its hard to tell from a low res graphic, it almost looks like that's actual paint and they've cut around brush strokes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion guys, I've recently came across this tutorial, I might suggest that author used displacement tool from CINEMA4D on top of gradient image and made a shoot under specific angle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCdmhYGZ-qo

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49087/discussion-on-question-by-adrian-sol-interesting-effect-from-where-to-start).

Comment: have you tried [asking the author of the poster?](https://www.behance.net/gallery/43905933/Baugasm-Series-Pack-2) Maybe you can get the answer from him :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. It is difficult to guess what is the exact process. For example, there are some programs that try to mimic particles and inclusive moving particles. For example this: http://www.escapemotions.com/experiments/fluid_painter/

I will try to do some experiments later but one option is to start in Photoshop with a simple black and white noise and start smearing it in the desired direction.

I think you can try in a low resolution and resample it later.

I would use separated layers and you can change the color of the layer and not contaminate the adjacent colors.

Another option would be trying with a painting program, like Corel Painter or the free one MyPaint, or Dogwaffle.

Note that this is not a definitive answer, but does answer:

> tips in order to start moving on

n_n

---

One first example. This is a test on Dogwaffle Artist 9 using some particle brushes directly:

[image]

One more place to explore is using a pressure sensitive tablet.

In photoshop you can change the dynamics of any brush, sometimes the pressure changes opacity or color. In this case, you want to change size.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the scribble or zig-zag tools in illustrator applied to brush strokes.

Answer (score -1):

you can do the following things:-

1.download some photoshop brush and use with change opacity.
2.use texture and pattern.
3.blending mode is very useful.
4.go to filter option and use another effect like blur and more.
5.use proper typography.

Hope it will helpful to you.

Comment: Hi Durgesh and welcome to GD.SE! Since this is a Q&A site and not a forum, we're looking for more specific answers to the questions that are posted. Please take a look at the [Help Center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information and possibly refine one of the options you have listed in this answer. Thank you for contributing and have fun!